# rc-calendar displaying inside react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to implement a prototype with rc calendar package.
- so I included the dpendency in stackblitz
- but the problem is I am not able to see the calendar similar to the way they show it in their screenshots.
- I looked into their props but not sure how to format it.
- can you tell me how to show the calendar similar to their demo.
- providing by code snippet and stackblitz below.

demo https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-calendar#screenshots
not working code  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b2d3rb?file=demo.js

```
class SimpleMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      value1: "",
      display: false,
      chipName: "",
      value2: ""
    };

  }



  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
        <Calendar />

    );
  }
}

export default SimpleMenu;
```

Comment: You have no css in your component.  In their examples, they are importing a css file, though they don't specifically seem to mention it in their documentation for some reason.

Comment: @sn3ll ey thanks...it worked in case if I wanted to make the active date to green color and change the whole background from white to red...how can I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sn3ll is right. Just add the css

```
import "rc-calendar/assets/index.css"
```

Comment: @Jihal hey thanks...it worked in case if I wanted to make the active date to green color and change the whole background from white to red...how can I do it